# Are ancestor path queries strongly consistent if combined with other queries in the Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have Child entity and a Parent entity. They are grouped into a Entity group through an ancestor path.

According to the documentation, if I query for all the children belonging to a parent using an ancestor query I will always get strongly consistent data. However, if I combine this query with another query (such as finding all the children that are older than 18 years), will the overall query also be strongly consistent?

So for example, let's say that I want to get all the male children belonging to particular parent. Will this query be strongly consistent or eventual consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what an ancestor query is. As long as you use an ancestor in your query, it is strongly consistent.